# How to provide permission to the user to access only one column in the created Microsoft Lists?

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, microsoft365

Am new to Microsoft Lists and trying to implement the library management system. Have prepared a list to show the book details using the 'From Excel' list. Need to restrict the permission based on the user role(admin, client).

For example, If a user needs to request a book, there might be a column to access for the user to send a request for the desired book. So that, an admin will get notified for the request and take action.

Similarly, from the list i created, i need to provide permission to the user to access only one column. The rest of the column can only be for view purposes.

Note: As i searched i found we can set permission like view, view, and edit, and stop sharing the list based on the roles of Members, Owners, and Visitors.

Could anyone please guide me on this?

Regards,
Vadivel

Answer (score 0):

@Karthi,

It's not possible to configure column permission, the least permission is item-level. There is no column-level or view level permission.

Here are 2 possible solutions:

- Make the target column read-only. Then develop another interface for the administrator to manage the data. For example, through SharePoint rest API, we can turn the column back to editable and post updates then immediately turn it to read-only.

> Check [Set List Column Read Only in SharePoint using PowerShell](https://www.codesharepoint.com/powershell/set-list-column-read-only-in-sharepoint-using-powershell)

> [How to update read only field](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9adffd13-c534-4b6c-b9aa-78d9b7659def/is-there-a-way-to-update-the-editor-and-author-of-an-list-item-using-just-rest-api?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

- Hide the target column and make a calculated column then set its value equal to the target column. The user will only see those calculated columns, any updates on the target column will be reflected in calculated columns.

> Check [Make SharePoint Columns read-only without coding](https://devscopeninjas.azurewebsites.net/2019/03/13/make-sharepoint-columns-read-only/)